# Encountering an error trying to create functions in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to create a function that will authenticate a URL for a fetch request. However whenever I try to call this function in app.post callback I get this error on my nodejs server: "TypeError: authenticateUrl(...) is not a function". Do you have to approach functions in a different way with nodejs?

```
const express = require("express");
const fetch = require("isomorphic-fetch");
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

/* Functions */

function authenticateUrl(url) {
  let urlHttps = url.slice(0, 7);
  let testUrl = "https://";

  if (urlHttps !== testUrl) {
    url = testUrl + url;
  }
  console.log(url);
  return url;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////
console.log("test");

const app = express();

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Thanks for posting that");
  console.log(req.body);
  const website = req.body.websiteOption;
  console.log(website);
  const authenticatedWebsite = authenticateUrl(website)

  


(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(authenticatedWebsite);
      // console.log(response)
      const text = await response.text();
      // console.log(text)
      const dom = await new JSDOM(text);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })();
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Remove the wrapper around the try catch block and use `app.post("/", async function (req, res) {` instead

Comment: Put a semicolon after `authenticateUrl(website)`. Even though there's line breaks between that and the async line below it, in Javascript it's trying to do `authenticateUrl(website)(otherstuff)` - which is valid Javascript. Omitting semicolons causes ambiguous issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem over here is that you have not added a semi-colon before defining the function. A semi-colon should be added before an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) to prevent any previous code from executing your code as the arguments to a function.
You can fix this problem by adding a semicolon after this statement, which comes before the IIFE.

```js
const authenticatedWebsite = authenticateUrl(website);
```

After adding a semi-colon, you can add your function below, just as it is.

```
(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(authenticatedWebsite);
      // console.log(response)
      const text = await response.text();
      // console.log(text)
      const dom = await new JSDOM(text);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })();
});
```

I hope this helped you.